# swift how to pass image to a clickable tableview cell?

Tags: swift2, uiimage, segue, uitableview

I am making a tableview that the user can press and get more detailed information from the pressed cell. However, I am having some trouble on how to get the UIimage to work.

my code is the following:

```
let shotMatchSegue = "ShowMatchSegue"
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == shotMatchSegue,
    let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? MatchViewController, 
    matchIndex = recentMatchesTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
    {
        destination.matchChampionImage = UIImage(named: "\(championsPlayed[matchIndex])_Splash_Tile_0")
        destination.matchType = gameType[matchIndex]
    }
}
```

on my MatchViewController, i have the following:

@IBOutlet weak var gameMatchChampionIcon: UIImageView!

```
@IBOutlet weak var gameMatchType: UILabel!
var matchType = String()
var championIcon = String()
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    gameMatchChampionIcon.image = UIImage()
    gameMatchType.text = matchType
}
```

I can imagine it's most likely the case that I set up my gameMatchChampionIcon.image = UIImage() wrong. So I am wondering what is the correct way to setup if I want to pass in images to the UIimage

thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get image this type of inside your code.

```
@IBOutlet weak var gameMatchType: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var gameMatchChampionIcon: UIImageView?
    var photo: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            gameMatchChampionIcon?.image = photo
        }
    }
var matchType = String()
var championIcon = String()
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    gameMatchChampionIcon?.image = photo
    gameMatchType.text = matchType
}
```

and pass your image in the segue to photo variable

```
destination.photo = UIImage(named: "\(championsPlayed[matchIndex])_Splash_Tile_0")
```